# Dynamic Whitespace Generation is done incorrectly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to generate dynamic whitespace to perform a drag and drop as done in this example: [text](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmrcb1-qpmaxl?file=src%2Fmain.ts)
The problem arises at the moment when the main array only finds the famous '$$_$$' once since at the html level it is generating 2 boxes.

As a result of this problem I have been trying to change the interfaces to go from a two-dimensional array to of a dimension

```
export interface QuestionDetails {
  questions: Array<string>;
  options: Array<string>;
  answers: Array<string>;
}
```

And modifying the logic but I have not achieved it, with this is there something I should consider to display correctly the boxes considering de text that generate the blank spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a dynamic drag-and-drop quiz setup where the objective is to let users drag options and drop them into blanks within a sentence or a paragraph. I understand that you want to transition from a two-dimensional array to a single-dimension array.

Considering the described structure of the `QuestionDetails` interface, here's a simple way you can structure your logic:

1. **Questions Array** - Instead of holding the actual questions, this array could hold the structures or patterns of the questions. For instance, `["The capital of $$_$$ is $$_$$", "The $$_$$ revolves around the sun."]`.
2. **Options Array** - This array would simply have the actual drag-and-drop options, e.g. `["Earth", "France", "Paris"]`.
3. **Answers Array** - This would hold the correct answers in the order that they would fit in the questions, e.g. `["France", "Paris", "Earth"]`.

Now, when you want to display the question with blanks, you would:

- Parse the `questions` array.
- Every time you find a `$$_$$`, replace it with a drag-and-drop slot (or a placeholder) where users can drop their answers.

Here's an example of how you might implement this:

**HTML:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let question of questionDetails.questions; let i = index">
  <span *ngFor="let part of question.split('$$_$$')">
    {{ part }}
    <div *ngIf="i < question.split('$$_$$').length - 1" class="drop-zone">
      <!-- Your drag-and-drop placeholder -->
    </div>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="options">
  <div *ngFor="let option of questionDetails.options" class="draggable-option">
    {{ option }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (just a basic example, adapt as needed):**

```css
.drop-zone {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.draggable-option {
  /* Some styling to show these are draggable items */
}
```

**Component:**

```js
questionDetails: QuestionDetails = {
  questions: ["The capital of $$_$$ is $$_$$", "The $$_$$ revolves around the sun."],
  options: ["Earth", "France", "Paris"],
  answers: ["France", "Paris", "Earth"]
};

// rest of your component logic...
```

**Note:** This is a very high-level overview. The drag-and-drop logic itself would require a more detailed implementation, likely using a library like Angular's DragDrop module.

Finally, remember that your data structure should reflect the nature of your quiz. If questions only have one blank, your structure would be different from questions that might have multiple blanks. Adjust accordingly.